# Unable to create Big Query Data Transfer job using a service account

Tags: google-bigquery

Am not able to create a data transfer job between a google playstore store to a google storage bucket using a service account that has permissions for both. I am able to create a transfer job using my project account which only has access to the storage bucket so I cannot use this in production.

By running the following:

```bash
bq mk --transfer_config --target_dataset=<my dataset> --display_name=<My Transfer Job> --params='{"bucket":<playstore bucket>,"table_suffix":<my suffix>}' --data_source=play --service_account <service account email> --service_account_credential_file $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

I am getting error:

> Unexpected exception in GetCredentialsFromFlags operation: Credentials
>   appear corrupt. Please delete the credential file and try your command
>   again. You can delete your credential file using "bq init
>   --delete_credentials".

Did a bq init and reran bq cmd but getting same error.
Also activated service acct using below cmd; still same error.

```bash
gcloud auth activate-service-account <service account email> --key-file $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

Comment: Hi Nancy and welcome to SO. What OS are you using? Can you run echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and share the result. I have been using this command for a while with no issues so I can it's something local to your machine or your shell setting / permission

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tamir. The env var does resolve correctly to my service account credential file, project-id-blah-blah-blah.json

Comment: I can only suggest to try and generate a new service account JSON key and start the process from scratch hope this will help.